# Wordpress 6.2.2 with WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker - Multilevel menues not working

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am using WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker with following code;

```
            <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'header_menu_location',
            'depth'             =>  3,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
        ) );
        ?>
```

I cannot get any nested menus to work.  I have tried;

I have tried withing "depth" parameter set but they my entire dropdown disappears.  I read that without the parameter set, its default is 0 meaning all multilevel menus should work.

I have tried with depth=3 and I only get a main menu item with a dropdown of other menu items, however, once I nest a menu item, the nested item will not appear.

Any other ideas appreciated.